# python-clang: Getting Template Arguments

Tags: python, c++, libclang

I'm trying to extract the template arguments from class instantiations in C++ using `python-clang`, ie. the Python bindings for `libclang` (with `clang` 3.9). For example, for

```
template <typename T> class X {};
X<bool> x;
```

I'd like to be able to figure out that `X` is instantiated with a `bool` as its template parameter.

First, it seems that some functions, such as `get_num_template_arguments`, are not exposed via `python-clang` in the first place, which is where [cymbal](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cymbal/1.0.0) seems to come into play to monkey-patch `python-clang`.

With this, I was able to get this far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import clang.cindex

clang.cindex.Config.set_library_file('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-3.9.so.1')

index = clang.cindex.Index.create()

source = """
template <typename T> class X {};
X<bool> x;
"""

######### stolen from cymbal

from ctypes import c_uint, c_int

def find_libclang_function(function):
    return getattr(clang.cindex.conf.lib, function)

def monkeypatch_helper(classtype, name, library_function, args, result):
    if hasattr(classtype, name):
        raise ('failed to add method, %s is already available' % name) 
    f = find_libclang_function(library_function)
    f.argtypes = args
    f.restype = result
    def impl(*args):
        return f(*args)
    setattr(classtype, name, impl)

def monkeypatch_type(method_name, library_function, args, result):
    monkeypatch_helper(clang.cindex.Type, method_name, library_function, args, result)



monkeypatch_type('get_template_argument_type',
                        'clang_Type_getTemplateArgumentAsType',
                        [clang.cindex.Type, c_uint],
                        clang.cindex.Type)

monkeypatch_type('get_num_template_arguments',
                        'clang_Type_getNumTemplateArguments',
                        [clang.cindex.Type],
                        c_int)
######### /stolen from cymbal

# helpers for visiting the AST recursively
def visit(node, func):
    func(node)
    for c in node.get_children():
        visit(c, func)

def visit_depth(node, func, depth=0):
    func(node, depth)
    for c in node.get_children():
        visit_depth(c, func, depth+1)

# parse the TU
tu = clang.cindex.TranslationUnit.from_source('t.cpp', ['-std=c++11'], unsaved_files=[('t.cpp', source)])

# show the AST
def astprinter(node, depth):
    print " "*depth, node.kind, node.spelling
visit_depth(tu.cursor, astprinter)    

# find everything with a template and try to extract the template argument
def template_finder(node):
    if hasattr(node, 'type') and node.type.get_num_template_arguments() != -1:
        print node.type.get_num_template_arguments(), node.spelling, node.kind, node.get_template_argument_type(0).kind
visit(tu.cursor, template_finder)
```

This outputs:

```
 CursorKind.TRANSLATION_UNIT t.cpp
  CursorKind.CLASS_TEMPLATE X
   CursorKind.TEMPLATE_TYPE_PARAMETER T
  CursorKind.VAR_DECL x
   CursorKind.TEMPLATE_REF X
   CursorKind.CALL_EXPR X
1 x CursorKind.VAR_DECL TypeKind.INVALID
1 X CursorKind.CALL_EXPR TypeKind.INVALID
```

I was expecting the `node.get_template_argument_type(0).kind` in `template_finder` to return something to lead me to `bool`, but I couldn't find anything. Is this the right way to go? Is it even possible to get the template arguments in the current state of `python-clang`?

Comment: Just a clarification about cymbal - it was very much a stop-gap that was put in place to prevent anyone from having to copy and paste code to inject functions using ctypes. 

Since it was released, there have been some important refactorings (eg/ clang.cindex >= 3.9 now has a register_function), which make it far less important.

Comment: Also on the licensing for cymbal - it's published under the MIT license, so it's fine to reuse / recycle any code you like, provided you make suitable attribution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you're really missing is `.type` in a couple of places in template finder, but for reference, this works for me, even on clang as old as 3.7

```
import clang.cindex
from clang.cindex import *
import cymbal
from ctypes import *

cymbal.monkeypatch_type('get_template_argument_type',
                        'clang_Type_getTemplateArgumentAsType',
                        [Type, c_uint],
                        Type)

cymbal.monkeypatch_type('get_num_template_arguments',
                        'clang_Type_getNumTemplateArguments',
                        [Type],
                        c_int)


# check if the cursor's type is a template
def is_template(node):
    return hasattr(node, 'type') and node.type.get_num_template_arguments() != -1

index = clang.cindex.Index.create()

source = """
template <typename T> class X {};
X<bool> x;
"""
# parse the TU
tu = clang.cindex.TranslationUnit.from_source('t.cpp', ['-std=c++11'], unsaved_files=[('t.cpp', source)])

for c in tu.cursor.walk_preorder():
    if is_template(c):
        t = c.type
        print t.kind, t.spelling, t.get_num_template_arguments()
        print t.get_template_argument_type(0).spelling
```

Which gives:

```
TypeKind.UNEXPOSED X<bool> 1
bool
TypeKind.UNEXPOSED X<bool> 1
bool
```

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks -- also for the clarification regarding cymbal, I'll look into that.